# Iphone media queries not working on safari

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have wriiten below css for iphone 5s for menu. It works properly for chrome browser in windows but when i check it on mac in safari browser for iphone 5s, it does not works.

```css
    /* Code for mobile menu */
.mobile-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background: rgba(56, 72, 142, 0.5);
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.mobile-menu ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.mobile-menu ul li {
  padding: 11px 10px 10px 15px;
}
.mobile-menu ul li a {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.mobile-menu ul li i {
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

@media screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 568px) and (orientation: portrait) {
  .mobile-menu ul {
    top: 75px !important;
    transform: translateY(0) !important;
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 568px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  .mobile-menu ul {
    top: 0 !important;
    transform: translateY(0) !important;
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile-menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="homemenu-blue-bkg"><a href="#"><i class="icon-home"></i>Home</a></li>
    <li class="srt-bkg active"><a href="#"><i class="icon-srt"></i>Share Registry & Transfer</a></li>
    <li class="payroll-bkg active"><a href="#"><i class="icon-pp"></i>Payroll Processing</a></li>
    <li class="trust-bkg active"><a href="#"><i class="icon-ta"></i>Trust Administration</a></li>
    <li class="rms-bkg active"><a href="#"><i class="icon-rms"></i>Record Management Services</a></li>
    <li class="dsc-bkg active"><a href="#"><i class="icon-dsc"></i>Digital Signature Certification</a></li>
    <li class="cfdm-bkg active"><a href="#"><i class="icon-cfdm"></i>Corporate F D Management</a></li>
    <li class="career-bkg"><a href="#"><i class="icon-career"></i>Join TSRDarashaw</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Also it should be center vertically for all mobiles.